# Minimize intergral - linear algebra 2 - Inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $V=\mathbb{R}_7[x]$. Then define the inner product$$\langle f,g\rangle =\int \limits _0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx.$$A) Apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure to $\{1,x,x^2\}$

B) For $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, minimize the integral:$$\int \limits _0^1\left (x^3-ax^2-bx-c\right )^2\,dx.$$**My attempts**

A) Easy, found an orthogonal base, is: $\left \{1,x-\dfrac{1}{2},x^2-x+\dfrac{1}{6}\right \}$.

B) If I am doing the formula for it, I will get:$$\left \langle x^3-ax^2-bx-c,1 \right \rangle$$and like that for $x-\dfrac{1}{2}$ and for $x^2-x+\dfrac{1}{6}$, which seems like a lot of algebra.

Is there any other way to do it?

Its not realistic to do it this way... It will take me over 3 hours just to calculate it all...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is an useful reference to write using mathjax.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia Hi, what is the problem exactly? I wrote integrals and all pretty good, I really dont seem to understand what is the problem. I am not a new person, I wrote good questions and all, didnt seem to be a problem in other topics.

Comment: It is just a suggestion.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia Yea, but if you are suggesting, It seems there is a problem with my mathjax writing, I really want to know, if it will make a difference.

Comment: I have edited in order to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia oh you did $$something$$ to put in the middle. I see. Thanks! Oh and you also put the <> thingy, I didnt know there was a way to do it, thoughts that is how I do it.

Comment: You're looking for the orthogonal projection of the given polynomial to the orthogonal complement of $1$.

Comment: @Berci say, what? sorry I dont really know. I am trying to understand B). I can find a solution for it, but it will be 3 pages and a few hours at least. I already found orthogonal base and yea, you are talking about projection, if I am using that forumla, it will be a long way to find it ( 3 pages and a few hours jusst to calculate numbers with sqrt and such )

Comment: You don't need to care about $x$ and $x^2$ only $1$.

Comment: @Berci I cant really understand what you said? Did I do wrong when I said what I should do? cus that is what seems most logical, but problem is that it is long...

Comment: Why would you do anything (and what) with the other two basis elements? The requested integral is just the same as the inner product $\langle x^3-ax^2-bx-c,\,1\rangle$. However.. are you sure there isn't a square of the integrand in this integral to minimize? For that question you could nicely use your orthogonal basis.

Comment: @Berci oh wait, I forgot the square... how did you know? wow, you are genius, seriously..  I did not notice the square, how does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t:=t(x):=ax^2+bx+c$, then we want to minimize $\int_0^1(x^3-t(x))^2\,dx$.
Observe that, by definition of the given inner product, it equals to $\langle x^3-t,\, x^3-t\rangle\ =\ \|x^3-t\|^2$ with the induced norm.

So we want to minimize the distance of $x^3$ and $t$ where $t$ runs through all (at most) quadratic polynomials $t\in\Bbb R_2[x]$.
For classical inner product, geometrically it would mean to take the orthogonal projection of the vector $x^3$ to the subspace $\Bbb R_2[x]$.

Since you already have an orthogonal basis of $\Bbb R_2[x]$, you basically just need to take the 3 inner products of $x^3$ with the basis elements and do some algebra to identify $a,b,c$.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the explanation, since my English is not that good, what does it mean to take the 3 inner products of $x^3$ with the basis elements and do some algebra? Sorry again.

Comment: If $a,b$ is an *orthonormal* basis of a plane $S$ in classical 3d Euclidean space, then for any vector $v$, its orthogonal projection to $S$ is $\langle v,a\rangle\cdot a + \langle v,b\rangle\cdot b$. Exactly the same pattern goes on for a general inner product and bigger subspace. I'm not entirely sure that your basis $1,\, x-1/2,\, x^2-x+1/6$ is ortho*normal*, I haven't checked.

Comment: Oh it is orthogonal base, that is what they asked at A no? apply G.S, which means orthogonal base.

Comment: I will do now orthonormal base and update.

Comment: Well, there are more versions of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. Sometimes an orthogonal basis suffices.

Comment: Ahh, I see.. in a few minutes I will update if I will have any problem, thanks!

Comment: Okay, found the orthonormal base. Now, since my english is not at its best, I want to verify:
I have $\varepsilon_1$, $\varepsilon_2$, $\varepsilon_3$. now, I have to do what exactly? I really am trying to understand, but its hard. ( EDIT: I think I know,  I will update ).

Comment: The question is, what is vector $v$? I know that I have $a$,$b$,$c$, which are the epsilons. but v is $x^3$ or the something else? if yes \ not, please explain why is it like that.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it, thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see any $v$ anywhere, so it's hard to answer.

Comment: Oh it is all good, I got it solved, thanks for the help, what you said helped me enough!